# Do we need to use API key for Google Geocoding API in production

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-geocoding-api

I created a small project.  I am using google geocoding API to get the latitude and longitude.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding

Sample Request:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=true

Now I going to production.  I am not using the commercial account.  Do i need to add the KEY to my Request or not

Can some one tell whether to use the KEY or NOT

Comment: Thank you Andrew for the reply.  I am sorry I didn't get you what your asking .

Comment: I am asking if you have tried to send the request without the key.

Comment: ya it is working
please, try the following link

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=true

Answer (score 0):

It's not required to use the key, but you should(the explanation may be found in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#api_key))

Especially the key-based quota is important. When the domain you are using shares the IP with other domains you will share the quota for geocoding with all the other domains when you don't use a key. Of course this wouldn't be acceptable in production(at least for me)

Answer (score 0):

@andrew
API Keys used for security and Google limits the free quota usage at some level.in production when your traffic gets increase you will need a billing account and billing account only works with API KEYs.

Google Maps Platform products are secured from unauthorized use by restricting API calls to those that provide proper authentication credentials. These credentials are in the form of an API key - a unique alphanumeric string that associates your Google billing account with your project, and with the specific API or SDK.